# The HTTP status code "8" is not valid, issues on redirect

Tags: laravel

I've been building a mini social network on my own for learning purposes in Laravel. I'm having an issue when I want to update some of my data on the profile that I made. 8 is my id.

This is the form I'm using for the update :

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' =>  ['edit_user',$user-> id],'id' => 'form_sample_1','class'=>'form-horizontal','novalidate' => 'novalidate','role' => 'form')) !!}
{!! csrf_field() !!}
   <div class="form-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button> You have some form errors. Please check below. </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name
                <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="name" data-required="1" value="{{$user->name}}" class="form-control">
                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Email
                <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$user->email}}" >
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn grey-salsa btn-outline">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

this is the function :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name'=>'required|max:255',
            'email'=>'required|unique:users|max:255'
        ));

    $user= User::find($id);

    //echo $user->name;

    //echo $request->name;

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->user_modify_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if($user->email != $request->email)
    {
        $user->email = $request->email;
    }

    if($user->save())
    {
        return redirect('user_profile',$id)->with('success', sprintf('User: "%s" successfully saved.', $user->name));
    }else if ($validation->fails())
    {   echo 'undone';
        return redirect('user_profile',$id.'#tab_1-1');
    }

}
```

this is the route on the routes file :

```
Route::post('edit_user/{user}',array('as' => 'edit_user','middleware' => 'auth','uses' => 'UserController@update'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the redirect function is the status code.

Try using the route helper function to crerate the proper URL:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route

```
return redirect(route('user_profile',$id.'#tab_1-1'));
```